# Nuxt WARN Cannot stringify a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I got warn message on nuxt server side

I set static js file in store/menu.js

menu.js file include object, and the object has function like bottom

```js
// store/menu.js
const obj = {
 examMethod: () => console.log(123)
}
```

When I googled, I think @nuxt/devalue library is causing problems,
what should i do?

Comment: You can't send functions to the client

Comment: Isn't that possible?
I imported store/menu.js at store/user.js

I'm using store/user.js as a vuex store
store/menu.js is just Object file has functions.